# Complex Minimum of Rolling Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I'm working on a complex statistical function that requires finding the minimum of 10 previous computed values. The computed values for each of the previous rows are dependent not only on the average from current row, but the previous rows calculations as well. The below illustration shows the desired query result:

[image: Illustration]

I am able to get the 10 day average, but am stumped on how to apply the other calculations without the use of a window function for every individual scenario which would be very inefficient. Below is the code I have so far:

```
CREATE TABLE #TBL(
[id]    int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[price] numeric(20,10)
)

INSERT INTO #TBL ([price])
VALUES (93.02),(90.56),(88.63),(90.3),(91.58),(90.42),(89.5),(89.23),(87.07),(85.88),(86.04),(87.26),(87.67),(84.37),(84.13),(83.3),(82.4),(81.73),(82),(80.69),(82.13)


SELECT
    [id], [price],
    CASE WHEN [id] >= 10 THEN
    avg([price]) OVER(ORDER BY ID ASC ROWS BETWEEN 9 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
    END  AS [average (last 10)]
FROM #TBL
```

Any help on creating an efficient query would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #TBL(
[id]    int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL primary key clustered, --!!!!
[price] numeric(20,10)
)

INSERT INTO #TBL ([price])
VALUES (93.02),(90.56),(88.63),(90.3),(91.58),(90.42),(89.5),(89.23),(87.07),(85.88),(86.04),(87.26),(87.67),(84.37),(84.13),(83.3),(82.4),(81.73),(82),(80.69),(82.13)

select *
from
(
  select *, avg([price]) OVER(ORDER BY ID ASC ROWS BETWEEN 9 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as avg10
  from #TBL 
) as a
outer apply
(

   select min(r.runningdiff) as mindiff
   from
   (
      select sum(l10.diff) over (order by l10.id) as runningdiff
      from
      (
        select TOP (10) b.id, a.avg10 - b.price as diff
        from #Tbl as b
        where 1=1
        and a.Id >= 10
        and b.Id between a.id-9 and a.Id
      ) as l10
   ) as r
) as rt
```